# Change author slug and functionality

Tags: permalinks, templates, url-rewriting, author, slug

Please help me solve this problems:

## Problem 1

AFAIK,

```
http://exmaple.com/author
```

maps to nothing (a **404 error** page) and

```
http://exmaple.com/author/{username}
```

maps to **posts authored by** `{username}`. I need to change this behavior to something else:

1. I need that `http://example.com/author` maps to **list of authors**
2. I need that `http://example.com/author/{username}` maps to some **profile information** (I hope this could be done by adding a template file like `author.php` in theme's root)

## Problem 2

At the same time, I need to prepend all of my posts with `/blog` like:

```
http://example.com/blog/this-is-my-first-post
```

It could be done by changing **Permalinks Structure** to `/blog/%post_name%`, but it changes the `author` url too:

```
http://example.com/blog/author
http://example.com/blog/author/{username}
```

which **is not desired** in my case.

## Please help me:

1. prepend **ONLY** posts with `/blog`
2. have a list of authors in `http://example.com/author`
3. have a user profile for all authors in `http://example.com/author/{username}`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

For the list of authors, the simplest solution is to create a page with the slug `author`, then create a `page-author.php` template where you'll add your own code to list authors.

All views in WordPress are a post or list of posts- there's no concept of an author list, or a list of terms in a taxonomy, those things need to be created manually.

For the author links, the fix is fairly simple, you can manually set the structure they follow to omit the `front` value that gets inserted by default:

```
function wpd_fix_author_structure(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_structure = 'author/%author%';
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_fix_author_structure' );
```

Don't forget to [flush rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after they change.

Comment: tnx, but if I go with 'page-author.php' how can I have routes for 'example.com/author/{username}

Comment: that's what the above code does.

Comment: Thank u very much, i'll give it a try and come back ASAP